# SVN : unknown host

Tags: svn, centos6

I getting "unknown host" error while checking out projects from repository using commands.

```
#svn co svn://abcd.com/repos/trunk1 test23
svn: Unknown hostname 'abcd.com'
```

I can ping host from same terminal as well as I can connect the SVN port through telnet on same machine. Only svn command unable to resolve the hosts.

```
#telnet abcd.com 3690
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to abcd.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops atomic-revprops partial-replay ) ) )
```

Second thing is I am facing this issue only for users other than root

Root user can successfully checkout projects from svn. Please help me to resolve this issue

- OS  : CentOS release 6.6
- svn : version 1.6.11

Comment: can you please explain for negative vote?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed for me. "Shell Fork Bomb Protection" was blocking SVN binary execution with non-root users.

```
CPANEL -> Securty center -> Shell Fork Bomb Protection -> Disable Protection
```

**"Unknown Hosts"** and **"Out of memory - terminating application"** both svn issues solved after disabling protection.